# How to add remote Git repo to local repo and keep it updated?

Tags: git, git-remote

I have authorization by `public_key` to remote repo and I can get everything from `http://someurl/first.git` on my local machine, but I have to populate this changes to other environments. To make it possible I have to put there my `private_key`, clone repo and switch to specified tag. But I don't want to do it because of security reasons.

I'm thinking about creation of my local repo `http://someurl/second.git`, committing all changes to it and deploy. But I have now idea how to add remote repo to my local? Is it possible? And how to commit to my local repo from remote and switch to needed tag?

Comment: What do you mean by "populate this changes to other envioronments"? What is this "local repo" you're talking about in "I'm thinking about creation of my local repo http://someurl/second.git, commiting all changes to it and deploy"? Deploy to where? You need to reword this question, I can't understand what you're trying to say. In general, adding a new remote can be done using the `git remote add` command - `git remote add second http://someurl/second.git` but I'm not sure this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Woudn't simply generating a different public/private key pair that's only used for distributing from the central repo to the others solve the "security reasons"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Noufal Ibrahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229602/noufal-ibrahim) should post his comment as an answer :

Use [`git remote add`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) to register a new remote repository, e.g. :

```
git remote add site2 http://someurl/second.git
```

After that, you can push from your local machine to this other repository :

```
git push site2 myBranch
```

Comment: I didn't find the question sufficiently clear to post an answer but if it works for the OP, well and good.